# Self-contained Java console input method?

Tags: java, exception, console, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I'm trying to write a self-contained (i.e. no need to open/close resources externally) method to obtain input from the console but am running into problems using it more than once.  I've tested it using both BufferedReader and Scanner:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      String str1 = getConsoleInputSc("Enter the 1st string: ");
        String str1 = getConsoleInputBR("Enter the 1st string: ");
        System.out.println(str1);
//      String str2 = getConsoleInputSc("Enter the 2nd string: ");
        String str2 = getConsoleInputBR("Enter the 2nd string: ");
        System.out.println(str2);
    }

    public static String getConsoleInputBR(String prompt) {
        String input = "";
        try (BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            input = bufferRead.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return input;
    }

    public static String getConsoleInputSc(String prompt) {
        String input = "";
        try (Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            input = scanIn.nextLine();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return input;
    }    
}
```

I'm using the try-with-resources statement to handle closing the resources.

Here's a sample run using the BufferedReader version:

```
Enter the 1st string: efsd
efsd
Enter the 2nd string: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
        at Test.getConsoleInputBR(Test.java:25)
        at Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

Here's a sample run using the Scanner version:

```
Enter the 1st string: sdfds
sdfds
Enter the 2nd string: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
        at Test.getConsoleInputSc(Test.java:3)
        at Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

I tried a couple of suggestions based on posts I found while looking up the "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found" exception (w/Scanner).  Using "while(scanIn.hasNextLine())..." I just get a continuous loop in the first call.  Using "if(scanIn.hasNextLine())" it never makes it to "input = scanIn.nextLine()" in the second call because the if clause returns false.

I get the feeling that these issues are related to the indeterminate nature of Java GC causing the resources not to be cleaned up/released properly but that's just a guess.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `FilterInputStream` classes typically close the wrapped `InputStream` on close. That's what `BufferedReader`'s `BufferedInputStream` is doing here.

Comment: I'm not following you.  How does that help in this situation?  It should be closed at the end of every call and a new one created/opened upon every call.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) the tutorial on `try-with-resources`.

When you declare the following

```
try (BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
```

when the code exits the `try` block, `close()` will be called on `bufferRead`, which will call `close()` on the wrapped `InputStreamReader` object, which will call `close()` on the object referenced by `System.in`, basically closing your standard input.

Don't close your standard input until your are certain you don't need it, basically never.

You'll have to rethink your design.

Comment: So are you saying that there is no way to write a self-contained method to do this and that I will have to maintain resources outside of this method?

That pretty much goes against OO principles.  This is so easy to do in C++; I have a hard time believing that it can't be done in Java.

Comment: @GaryWhite You can use a self-contained method to do it, just don't close the standard input.

Comment: Wouldn't that make it not self-contained if you have to handle resources external to the method?

Comment: @GaryWhite In that sense, fine. But you cannot create new standard inputs. There is only one such stream per process. If it's closed, there's no JDK way to re open it. But you can change what `System.in` is referencing.

Comment: Please explain "you can change what System.in is referencing".

Comment: @Gary The `System` class has a [`setIn(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn%28java.io.InputStream%29) method.

Comment: I looked it up but it's unclear to me as to how to use that in this case. The examples that I've found all reassign to a FileInputStream etc. so I don't know what I'd reassign it to, where I would do that or how that would help. I'm guessing that you're being cryptic in an attempt to "teach me how to fish" (which is sometimes a good thing) but this is beyond my ability to grok at this moment. I'm not looking for someone to write my code for me but just a strategy that I can understand. Is there any chance that you can throw me a bone and explain more fully?  Thanks.

Comment: @GaryWhite Sure. The standard input stream is provided by the OS. If you close it, there is no way to re-open within the same Java process. So you cannot use `System.in` inside a `try-with-resources` because it will eventually be closed. You need to keep it open if you intend to get input from it again. As such, I would say, it is impossible to keep it self contained and `System.in` is as close to a global variable as you can get in Java.

Comment: @GaryWhite I'd suggest keeping a `Scanner` object as an instance or class variable or pass it as an argument to your methods. Don't ever close it.

Comment: @GaryWhite Resources should be closed by the code that opens them. That is the correct pattern. You didn't open `System.in`, so you shouldn't be closing it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using try-with-resources like you are doing, just put the code in a simple try-catch block like this:

```
   public static String getConsoleInput(String prompt)
   {
      String input = "";
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      System.out.print(prompt);
      try {
         input = br.readLine();
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return input;
   }
```

This method worked fine when called by your code in main().  By not using try with resources, the resource is not automatically closed.

Comment: Thanks. I was under the assumption that it was not considered good practice to leave resources hanging. Is this one of those cases where I just need to ignore good practices?

Comment: It is not good practice to close System.in especially if your program intends to use it again.  In general, I think that System.in and System.out are things that are "left hanging" because the the JVM sets them up for you when it starts.  You should leave it up to the JVM to close these resources on the way out.

Comment: I guess that closing System.in was an unintentional side effect of closing the other resources.  I'll have to check to see if there's a way to disassociate System.in from those resources so that they can be closed.